# Why doesn't Class.forName work on grails domain classes

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy

I know that using `Class.forName` to load a grails domain class does not work, but I'm not sure why that is. I'm guessing there is some sort of grails magic happening but it would be nice to understand what it is.

I ended up using

```
GrailsDomainClass dc = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('mypack.myclass' )
def newDomainObject = dc.clazz.newInstance()
```

But I'm not sure why just doing `Class.forName('mypack.myclass')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grails uses custom classloaders, so you need to use the 3-arg variant with the classloader that Grails uses and registers as the context classloader:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName('mypack.myclass', true, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
def newDomainObject = clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: The custom classloader part makes sense, but using the 3 arg forName didn't seem to work. newInstance is returning null. I'm running this in BootStrap.groovy if that makes a difference.

Comment: `newInstance()` can't return null, it calls a constructor. It either succeeds or throws an exception. The default `toString()` that Grails adds will print a null id since it's a new non-persistent instance - is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Ah yes, that was the confusion. I was wondering how newInstance could return null. I thought maybe there was an exception under the hood or something that was getting swallowed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith We are also facing same issue but in our case we are using 3rd party library which requires CustomClassName and uses Class.forName() inside. We want to use our custom class here with that library, is there any way to resolve this in groovy on grails?

Comment: this did not work, newDomainObject  is [] instead of myclass instance, I'm still stuck and I can't find out how to instantiate a class with reflection within a grails application